# Swapping two elements in Doctrine ArrayColection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-odm

I have a document "Operation" in a symfony2 project that contains an embedded collection of other documents "Commands". I'm trying to write an action that swaps the position of two commands. I was trying to treat the collection as a normal PHP array but the behaviour was not as expected.

```php
class Operation
{
    ...
    /**
     * The sequence of commands
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Command")
     */
    protected $commands;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commands  = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->fallbacks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function swapCommands($index1, $index2)
    {
        $temp = $this->commands[$index1];
        $this->commands[$index1] = $this->commands[$index2];
        $this->commands[$index2] = $temp;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I `swapCommands()`, the affected elements fall the the bottom of the Array Collection. For instance, say I have the commands `['cd', 'ls', touch', 'mv']`. If I try to swap the indexes 0 and 1, I get `[touch', 'mv', 'ls', 'cd']`. How can I swap two elements in an array collection? My last resort will be to manually traverse the collection and `add()` each element...

Comment: your swap function works well... check how do you instantiate the commands (or dump it before swap)

Comment: Are you sure this is correct with ArrayCollections?

Comment: is not the better approach but is works: I try your code in my local environment without the mongo db. `$op = new Operation();
        $op->commands->add('cd');
        $op->commands->add('ls');
        $op->commands->add('touch');
        $op->commands->add('mv');
        $op->swapCommands(0,1);
        print_r($op->commands->toArray());die;
` and the output: `Array ( [0] => ls [1] => cd [2] => touch [3] => mv )`

Comment: Hm, you are adding strings to the commands array? Well, it doesn't work, so I'm adding each one for now :/

Comment: how do you populate the commands arraycollection? from mongo?

Comment: What are the values you are passion to swapCommand?

Comment: @Matteo the values are being added manually with $operation->addCommand($command) which receives a command.

Comment: @JasonRoman Those are the positions (indexes) in the array of the two elements I want to swap

Comment: I paste my code and work as expected, try to investigate in your `addCommand` method

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to make this work, but not the most elegant:

```php
public function swapCommands($index1, $index2)
{
    $arr  = $this->commands->toArray();
    $temp = $arr[$index1];
    $arr[$index1] = $arr[$index2];
    $arr[$index2] = $temp;

    $this->commands  = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $this->addCommand($arr[$i]);
    }
}
```